# IOS specific styles in vanilla nativescript

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

How can I write separate styles for iphone 6 and higher devices in vanilla nativescript. ??

I tried "page.ios.minW1080" but didn't work for me.

Any suggestions !!

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested in the answer to this question - Sagar1911 has found a solution and posted it [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/4877#issuecomment-331825604)